# How to create help for my functions written by in R?

Tags: r, function

I want to create help pages for my own functions. So if I define a function: e.g:

```
myfunct <- function(x,y,z){...}
```

And if I type `?myfunct` I'd get the parameter specifications that I give.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The only way to do exactly what you describe is to write your own [package](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).

Comment: (If you're using RStudio, though, creating a package is almost painfully easy.)

Answer (score 5):

You should create a package.
I suggest to use  the Roxygen package for documentation.

http://roxygen.org/
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html

In addition to ESS both rstudio http://www.rstudio.com/ide/ and statet http://www.walware.de/goto/statet support it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning roxygen/roxygen2.  Definitely makes life much easier.